# Java null pointer Exception Error in Objects

Tags: java, object, methods, error-handling, nullpointerexception

I wrote a program with objects and I get a NullPointerException error as I try to run it but I can't spot the exact problem with my code. Here it is (the bold line is where the eclipse points upon the error):

```
public class Cinema {
    private String cinemaName;
    private String Address;
    private Room Rooms[];
    private Movie Movies[];
    private final int MAX_NUM_MOVIES = 20;
    private final int MAX_NUM_ROOMS = 5;
    private int movieCounter;
    private int roomCounter;

    public Cinema(String cinemaName, String Address) {
        this.cinemaName = cinemaName;
        this.Address = Address;
        Room Rooms[] = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Movie Movies[] = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];
        movieCounter = 0;
        roomCounter = 0;
    }

    public boolean addMovieToCinema (Movie theMovie) {
        if (theMovie == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (movieCounter < MAX_NUM_MOVIES) {
            Movies[movieCounter] = new Movie(theMovie);
            movieCounter++;
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to "spot the the exact problem" with your code. You can look at the stack trace, which tells you exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: Eclipse tells you that you're using the `Movies` variable, which is  uninitialized. From there, your actual question should be *why isn't my variable initialized?*, and it has been answered.

Comment: Do you know why you put `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`? If you don't know what a warning is telling you, why don't you try to understand instead of telling it to shut up? :D That's actually the cause of your problem.

Comment: Post the stack trace no the NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning to these two member variables:

```
private Room Rooms[];
private Movie Movies[];
```

You declare new local variables with these two lines:

```
Room Rooms[] = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
Movie Movies[] = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];
```

Fix them to this to initialize your `Rooms` and `Movies` class members:

```
Rooms = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
Movies = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining this:

```
private Room Rooms[];
private Movie Movies[];
```

Why you just define a Collection!? Like:

```
private Collection<Room> rooms;
private Collection<Movie> movies;
```

And then, in your constructor you have to initialize your collections:

```
this.rooms = new ArrayList<>();
this.movies = new ArrayList<>();
```

I would say that this is the Java way. Also keep in mind that attribute names should be lower case.

Comment: This is not really an aswer to the question, but a side note. You should put it in a comment instead. I agree with you, though.

Comment: If the OP replaces his code by yours, he will have to replace more than that for it to compile. But indeed, I hadn't seen you dealt with the initialization problem.

Comment: Yeap. It was just a hint.

Comment: True, but given the knowledge of the OP regarding Java, maybe you should have given a little bit more info ;-) Anyway, have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

These two arrays should be class fields

```
private int movieCounter;
private int roomCounter;
private Room[] Rooms = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
private Movie[] Movies = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];

public Cinema(String cinemaName, String Address) {
  this.cinemaName = cinemaName;
  this.Address = Address;
  movieCounter = 0;
  roomCounter = 0;
}
```

Why don't you use Lists for storing Movies (and Rooms)? You don't have to provide the hardcoded limits.

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean addMovieToCinema(Movie theMovie) {
    if (theMovie == null) {
        return false;
    }
    movies.add( theMovie );
    return true;
}
```

Everything becomes simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your constructor hides your class member.

if you declare `private Movie Movies[];` then in your constructor you should write:  `Movies = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];`

When you wrote: `Movie Movies[] = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];` then you actually declare a new variable which is local to the constructor and that's why the class member `Movies` was null since it wasn't it who was initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your constructor for the Cinema class.
It should look like this :

```
   public Cinema(String cinemaName, String Address) {
    this.cinemaName = cinemaName;
    this.Address = Address;
// Remove type before variable to initialize class attribute instead of declaring a new varialble
    Rooms = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
// Remove type before variable to initialize class attribute instead of declaring a new varialble
    Movies = new Movie[MAX_NUM_MOVIES];
    movieCounter = 0;
    roomCounter = 0;
}
```

Class attribute will be initialized and the NullpointerException should disappear.

Cheers,
Sébastien.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to allocate memory when you declare the array:

```
private Room[] Rooms = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
```

Alternatively, if you want to allocate memory in your constructor you need:

```
Rooms = new Room[MAX_NUM_ROOMS];
```